# Can't get second monitor to work on 20.04 laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-prime

I've Acer VN7-792g laptop with iGPU and Nvidia, I try to get my second monitor to work on Ubnutu.
[Here a pastebin of lspci and lshw](https://pastebin.com/tPk0U4zq)

For now I've tried :

- Plug the monitor before, during or after boot
- Force both intel or nvidia driver in `xorg.conf`
- Use both `nvidia` or `nouveau` driver
- I've tested nvidia driver version : 380, 435, 450, 455

None of these gave any result.

Finally I tried to run these commands :

First I've got the modeline with : `cvt 1920 1080 60`

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00 --pos 0x0
```

With these commands I succeed to mirror the primary monitor, but if I try to change the `--pos` parameter, it's become a blank screen where I can move my mouse but not windows.

Here I've moved a terminal from the primary screen on left to center of this one.
[image: If I tried to move window]

Finally if I type `xrandr`, it say monitor disconnected on HDMI.

Thanks, Gwendal

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, too long a story for here, but just wanted to tell you that I have Nvidia driver version 450.80.02 and it is working fine now. I have a Dell G7.  Two external monitors, and this driver version is now working.
Not sure that helps you but it might.

Comment: Hi @Andrew and thank you for your answer, Have you some steps or tips to follow that works for you ?

Comment: I use Timeshift, so I just went back to a previous days version, and it worked for me.  Mine was working then it was not.  It seems the driver version above, 450.80.02 is the solution.  It was for me, and I hope it is for you.  There are many that have had this problem, so we are not alone.  I still don't entirely know what the issue is.  It is the biggest problem I have had since installing Ubuntu.  Almost the only real problem.  Wish I could help more.